# Config File cannot be saved for second instance WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, config

I am having an issue saving the config file when working with two instances of my program. I was able to reproduce this issue in a simple example project that looks like that:

```
Class MainWindow
   Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration

   Public Sub New()
      config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(e As CancelEventArgs)
      config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, True)
   End Sub
End Class
```

The first instance is saving the config on closing, but as soon as I am trying to close the second instance, config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, True) is throwing an error saying that the config file was changed by another program. I hope someone is able to help me with that problem. Thanks in advance.

edit: Forgot to delete the MyBase call

edit2: Tried Chillzy suggestion, but it fails as well.

```
   Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(e As CancelEventArgs)
      Dim mdate As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
      Dim mptpath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(config.FilePath) & "\" & mdate
      config.SaveAs(mdate, ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, True)
      File.Delete(fpath)
      File.Move(mptpath, fpath)
   End Sub
```

Comment: why are calling the same function in a loop? config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, True)
      MyBase.OnClosing(e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There. You copy load the config file then save as. Re-Read the saveas file as the current config file. on your way out you do the reverse

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
    Dim fpath As String = ""
    Dim mptpath As String = ""
    Public Sub New()
        config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        fpath = config.FilePath
        Dim mdate As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
        mptpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(config.FilePath) & "\" & mdate & ".config"
        config.SaveAs(mptpath, ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, True)
        config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(mptpath)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        File.Delete(fpath)
        config.SaveAs(fpath, ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, True)
        File.Delete(mptpath)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, Chillzy. Yes, I am running the application twice. Closed one app, trying to close the second one, then it crashes.

Comment: The process is closed, the problem is that the first instance is changing the config and that´s what the second instance notices when trying to close as well. I need a way to override the changes made by the first. If you have the opportunity to use VS, you can easily reproduce this issue,

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. While testing I noticed that SaveAs had no influence on my actual config file, since the method had created another config file. I tried your suggestion to erase and move, but that does not seem to do the job. See edit2

Answer (score 0):

You are making a loop by calling the OnClosing at the end of OnClosing

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(e As CancelEventArgs)
      config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, True)
  End Sub
```

Comment: go to your taskmanager and close all the process related to your app. they are still running in background because you created that endless loop. You can close you session on windows and re-open it. then try the code.